# How to render custom asset in liferay 7?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I created a custom entity and made it a custom asset. The entries are there in the database table `assetentry`.I want to render the asset in asset publisher. For this I made two classes `*AssetRenderer` and `*AssetRendererFactory` .I saw that `*AssetRendererFactory` constructor is being invoked but its `getAssetRenderer()` method is not being invoked. Any idea what might I be missing to render asset? Also I got my custom entity in the Asset type in the configuration link but when I select it, I got the contents of blogs portlet instead of my custom portlet. Please help.. any help would be appreciated. Thanx in advance..

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/rendering-an-asset

Comment: yes I checked the documentation and followed it but the same problem persists

Comment: do you see the components in gogo shell? First, check the bundles if it's installed and then use scr:list and scr:info to find out if the components are registered.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem as you described.

The main problem was that I hadn’t indexed my custom entity by searching engine (Elasticsearch). Therefore, Asset publisher could not find any instance of my custom entity (I don’t know why Asset publisher returns all contents of blog, but I had the same problem).

When I wrote an indexer for my custom entity based on https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/84418151 (deployed it and re-indexed custom entity), it started to work.